# How to select different frame in lldb?

Tags: lldb

How can I make `frame select` actually make the frame stay selected, instead of popping back to frame 0?

Here's the output explaining the problem:

```
(lldb) frame select 6
frame #6: 0x06b35dc9 Foundation`__57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 40
Foundation`__57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 40:
-> 0x6b35dc9:  addl   $24, %esp
   0x6b35dcc:  popl   %ebp
   0x6b35dcd:  ret    
   0x6b35dce:  nop    
(lldb) frame info
frame #0: 0x00c64123 Facebook`-[APHCurrentSession updateMessage:] + 1347 at APHCurrentSession.m:102
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug with Xcode and lldb.  Changing the selected thread and selected frame in the Debugger console window is lost immediately.  Or more accurately, lldb does not broadcast this state change to Xcode and Xcode, between commands, resets the debugger state to a known setup.  Unfortunately, until this is fixed you will need to do frame/thread changes using the GUI so Xcode can update the selected thread/frame.